# Regarding DHCP Discover, Offer, Request, and Ack

Tags: dhcp

In DHCP the initial Discover is a broadcast, but the remaining packets could be unicast.   How is that possible if the client does not yet have an IP address?

Answer (score 1):

IP address is used for routing packets across internet, so it's required for sending packet from one subnet to another. However, routing within subnet doesn't rely on IP address, but on MAC address only. Two devices can freely communicate using only their MAC addresses, and some local protocols don't include IP layer at all.

DHCP server is basically intended to be in the same subnet as requester (server can be in different subnet only if relay agents are configured to forward its packets to other subnets). Requester sends DISCOVER packet to broadcast MAC address, so it's delivered to all devices in subnet. Server learns requester's MAC from DISCOVER message and may (or may not) respond with unicast message by specifying destination MAC address instead of using boradcast MAC address.